# (pl/sql) Creating new DB when new row is inserted

Tags: sql, database, plsql

Is it possible to create a trigger which creates a new *DB* when a new row is inserted to an other DB?
For example: I've created a new DB called "Roles" which holds all the possible Roles exist in my program. When a user creates a new role (=add a new row to "Roles" DB), I want to create a new DB which its name is as the new role the user is adding at the same moment to "Roles" DB. 
(All I saw so far are triggers which update row/columns in existing DBs)

Thank you:)

Comment: Huh?  Even if this were possible, creating a new database under this circumstance is so far-fetched that database engines should not support it.  Perhaps you should just consider adding a row to an existing table.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: because the roles are not defined beforehand and each role is needed to be defined as DB.

Comment: I doubt you actually need to create a new DB for new roles, most probably a foreign key would be enough (role_id).

Comment: I think you are mixing terminologies here. Do you mean "table" instead of "db"?